# Spoof device as locked

Tags: jailbreak, ios

There is an app called "Pocket Points" where you gain points for having your phone locked in class. I am curious if there exists a tweak that can spoof your device being locked so that it registers as if the screen were locked and blacked out and gives you points, but you can still use the device normally. If this doesn't exist, is it even possible to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Flex](http://getdelta.co) to see if there is a simple method that it uses to detect whether the device is locked, at which point you can override the return boolean to always return true. Without being able to run the app, I can't create a patch myself, but search for methods with names such as ‘lock’.